# How To SSH From IPhone App

Tags: ios, ios4, ssh

So I have been looking every where, and so far i haven't been able to find anything that allows me to ssh from an iPhone app, and have finally resorted to posting a new pos.

So I am trying to make an app to manage servers and part of the tasks that I need to be able to do it to be able to some how remotely connect over the internet to a server with either an ip address or a DNS name.

The connection to the server does not necessarily need to be a SSH connection, it could be a telnet although because of the security issues i would prefer SSH (if it is a lot less code I would accept telnet), but on the other hand it could be some other type of connection.

The application just needs to be able to run a script on the server end and if a SSH or telnet I would not need any help but if some other type of connection i may need a bit of help. Also the server on the other end is intended to be linux server (either ubuntu or gentoo, but not sure which yet but all i can say is will almost certainly be a linux server operating system).

I have already looked at the libssh/2 and would welcome any other similar demos as have not been able to work out how get the frameworks to work as well as licensing issues with using the frameworks in it.

PS. I am relatively new to programming and although i have some basic knowledge of coding some type of tutorial or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks For Any Help

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH is a hugely complicated beast. As long as you only need to execute one command without interactivity, it sounds like you could achieve the same thing by running a web server on the server and posting the commands via HTTP from the device. You can use SSL to achieve security. You'll need a mechanism that allows you to authenticate the device (you'd need something with ssh, too). And you'll have to have something in the web server on the server that figures out and runs the desired script. But all that is still hugely easier than dealing with libssh.